# Openshift Online v2 MySQL binary logging

Tags: mysql, logging, binary, openshift

We are using the MySQL5.5 cartridge in Openshift Online v2 and would like to implement binary logging.

However, there is a warning at the top of my.cnf which says:

"# WARNING: Changes to this file will be lost on every restart/upgrade.  Configurable values can be set with environment variables through rhc env set..."

It appears the preferred method for setting binary logging is to add some entries to my.cnf and there are no environment variables covering binary logging.

Does anybody know of a workaround to get binary logging configured and working on MySQL5.5 cartridge in Openshift Online 2?

Thanks.

Robin

Comment: You can create your own cartridge (clone the original one) and include the `log-bin` setting in `conf/my.cnf.erb` (and of course preferable using an environment variable for it).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I think I found another workaround which does not involve creating a custom cartridge:

1. shut down mysqld using mysqladmin
2. append to my.cnf
3. start mysqld

I have tried this manually using a script and it seems to work.  Now a matter of implementing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround which does not involve creating a custom cartridge:

1. shut down mysqld using mysqladmin
2. append binary logging params to my.cnf
3. start mysqld

I have tried this manually using a script and it seems to work. Now a matter of implementing it properly.